# Display tweets from multiple users with a common hashtag

Tags: php, regex, api, twitter

I am building a program that displays a twitter feed of a specific set of users using a common hashtag. The program gets an array of usernames and a hashtag from user input in a form. I am using a regular expression (something I'm not very good with) to weed out the tweets containing the hashtag, which I then want to echo out. However, the program is currently not functioning. Here's my work:

```
    <?php
        $hash = $_GET['hash'];
        $users = $_GET['users'];
        $users = str_replace(" ", "", $users);
        $hash = str_replace(" ", "", $hash);
        $users = explode(",",$users);
        $regex = "/^[#]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ ]$/";
        $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.$user.'&lang=en&rpp=100';

        foreach($users as $user){
        $jsontwitter = file_get_contents($url);
        $twitter = json_decode($jsontwitter, true);
        $twittertext = $twitter["results"];

        if(preg_match($regex, $twittertext['text'])){
        foreach($twittertext as $text){
        echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$text['from_user'].'">@'.$text['from_user'].'</a>: '.$text['text'].'<br>';
            }
          }
        }
    ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should first correct typos. Your q= variable is empty because the variable on line 8 is not defined above. It appears you may have wanted to use '$users' there, as defined on line 3. I would test from the command line (as shown below) with static variable set on line 2 and 3. Place print statements throughout to determine your fail point.

$ php test.html
Warning: file_get_contents(http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&lang=en&rpp=100): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: the $url variable should actually be inside of the first foreach, which will define $user. but even after making this correction, there is no output.

Comment: I see that now. It wasn't immediately clear, because the $url request is outside the for loop. So you are requesting the feed for a user before their name is parsed from the array. It needs to be inside the for loop to grab each users' feed. Your next issue is that $twittertext, which you're trying to regex against is an array. I determined this by putting a print 'print $twittertext;' after that line and running it.

[root@fe02 htdocs]# php test.html<br>
Array

Comment: right, but wouldn't the loop be looking specifically at the ['text'] values in the decoded json, and not the rest of the the array?

Comment: The URI request needs to be in the loop, because that is when you are parsing the array of users and should be requesting their feed. Place print statements throughout your code where you expect to have certain information. You will see you have basic issues that need to be resolved before hitting the regex.

Comment: figured it out, with the help of a friend. the $url variable needed to be within the for loop in order to run the search with the defined $user variable. From there, the json is returned, decoded and the results are run through another for loop to isolate individual tweets that include the specified hashtag, using a regular expression in an if statement. the tweets are then echoed out.

Comment: additionally, the way the regular expression was treated was incorrect - it was looking for a string that begins with a # and included any characters, ending with a space. It should be looking for a string with a # anywhere in it, that is followed by the $hash variable, followed by a space.  unfortunately, i can't post the answer yet, with the resulting script.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, with the help of a friend. the $url variable needed to be within the for loop in order to run the search with the defined $user variable. From there, the json is returned, decoded and the results are run through another for loop to isolate individual tweets that include the specified hashtag, using a regular expression in an if statement. the tweets are then echoed out. additionally, the way the regular expression was treated was incorrect - it was looking for a string that begins with a # and included any characters, ending with a space. It should be looking for a string with a # anywhere in it, that is followed by the $hash variable, followed by a space.

The resulting, working script:

```
<?php
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$users = $_GET['users'];

$users = str_replace(" ", "", $users);
$hash = str_replace(" ", "", $hash);
$users = explode(",",$users);

$regex = "/($i)#". $hash ."/";


foreach($users as $user){

    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.$user.'&lang=en&rpp=100';
    $jsontwitter = file_get_contents($url);
    $twitter = json_decode($jsontwitter, true);
    $twittertext = $twitter["results"];

    foreach($twittertext as $text){
        if(preg_match($regex, $text['text'])){
            echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$text['from_user'].'">@'.$text['from_user'].'</a>: '.$text['text'].'<br>';

        }
    }
}       

?>
```